# Creating a dynamic chart from django using chart.js

Tags: javascript, python, django, twitter

I’m new to Django. I’m currently doing sentiment analysis on real-time user tweets via Twitter API. I have managed to do the analysis and display the sentiments. Now, I want to visualize the sentiments using charts in my Django app (perhaps bar chart or pie chart) but I’m not sure how.

I was thinking of using Chart.js to make it responsive but most of the examples are using static data so I wasn’t successful in integrating my data where I extracted from Twitter API with chart.js.

This is a screenshot of my web page. The table was the extracted tweets with their corresponding sentiments. The bar chart however is just static data. I don't know how to convert it into json.

[screenshot of my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yiu58.png)

this is my `views.py`

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
from .forms import Sentiment_Typed_Tweet_analyse_form
from .sentiment_analysis_code import sentiment_analysis_code
from .forms import Sentiment_Imported_Tweet_analyse_form
from .tweepy_sentiment import Import_tweet_sentiment
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
      
def sentiment_analysis_import(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Sentiment_Imported_Tweet_analyse_form(request.POST)
        tweet_text = Import_tweet_sentiment()
        analyse = sentiment_analysis_code()

        if form.is_valid():
            handle = form.cleaned_data['sentiment_imported_tweet']
            # messages.info(request, 'It might take a while to load the data.')

            if handle[0]!='#':
                list_of_tweets = tweet_text.get_hashtag(handle)
                list_of_tweets_and_sentiments = []
                for i in list_of_tweets:
            

    list_of_tweets_and_sentiments.append((i,analyse.get_tweet_sentiment(i)))
                args = {'list_of_tweets_and_sentiments':list_of_tweets_and_sentiments, 'handle':handle}
                return render(request, 'home/sentiment_import_result_hashtag.html', args)
            
            if handle[0]=='#':
                list_of_tweets = tweet_text.get_hashtag(handle)
                list_of_tweets_and_sentiments = []
                for i in list_of_tweets:
                    list_of_tweets_and_sentiments.append((i,analyse.get_tweet_sentiment(i)))
                args = {'list_of_tweets_and_sentiments':list_of_tweets_and_sentiments, 'handle':handle}
                return render(request, 'home/sentiment_import_result_hashtag.html', args)
            
    else:
        form = Sentiment_Imported_Tweet_analyse_form()
        return render(request, 'home/sentiment_import.html')

def get_data(request, *args, **kwargs):
def get_data(request, *args, **kwargs):
    sentiment_analysis_import(args)
    data = {
        args
    }
    return JsonResponse('home/sentiment_import_result_hashtag.html', data)
```

This is my HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load static %}
  <head>
    <title>Sentymeter: Import Tweets</title>
   <!-- Required meta tags -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Chart js-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha256-Uv9BNBucvCPipKQ2NS9wYpJmi8DTOEfTA/nH2aoJALw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css" integrity="sha256-aa0xaJgmK/X74WM224KMQeNQC2xYKwlAt08oZqjeF0E=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
   <title>Import Tweets</title>

   <style>
     .tbl-header {
      border: 5px solid;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
     table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

th{
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e4e9e4;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
}

body,
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
            background: #f8f2ce !important;
        }
    h7.white-text {
         color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }
    
</style>
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>

  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/sentiment/type">Input Text</a>
        </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="/sentiment/import">Import Tweets<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="/feedback">Feedback</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <span class="hello-msg"><strong>Hello, {{request.user}}</strong></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn" ><a href="{% url 'user:logout' %}"><h7 class="white-text" color=white;>Logout</h7></a></button>
  </nav>


      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center ftco-vh-100">
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <h1 class="ftco-heading mb-3" >Import Tweets Result</h1>
            <h2 class="h5 ftco-subheading mb-5" ><strong>Keyword</strong> - {{ handle }}</h2>
      </div><div></div>   
      
      <div class = "container">
      
      <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="90" height="90"></canvas>

  {{ list_of_tweets_and_sentiments|json_script:"list_of_tweets_and_sentiments" }}
<!-- <script>
  const ctx = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('list_of_tweets_and_sentiments').textContent);
</script> -->


<script>
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Positive', 'Neutral', 'Negative'] ,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Sentiment Counts',
            data: [12, 19, 3],

            backgroundColor: [
                'green',
                'orange',
                'red',
            ],
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
</script></div>
 

<div class="tbl-header" >
    <table>
        <tr>
          <th >Tweet</th>
          <th>Sentiment</th>
          <th>Emotag</th>
        </tr>
      <tbody>
        {% for i,j in list_of_tweets_and_sentiments %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{i}}</td>
          <td>{{j}}</td>
          {% ifequal j 'Negative' %}
          <td><img src="{% static 'icons/negative.png' %}"></td>
          {% endifequal %}
          {% ifequal j 'Positive' %}
          <td><img src="{% static 'icons/positive.png' %}"></td>
          {% endifequal %}
          {% ifequal j 'Neutral' %}
          <td><img src="{% static 'icons/neutral.png' %}"></td>
          {% endifequal %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>


<h1>test</h1>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me on how to link my sentiment tweets with the chart? I am so confused right now…

Please let me know if you need other files/code.

Answer (score 0):

In most case Chart.js except either an array or an api call in JSON format.

If you are using Django you can create variable to be used in template and your data array for example :

```
Sentiment.filter(neutral=True).count() # return the number based on a specific filter
```

Pass it to a variable and in your template in the data array :

```
data: [{{neutral_sentiment}}, {{positive_sentiement}}, {{negative_sentiment}}],
```

-> variables containing the number to be use to generate the chart

I do that in most case, it works well if your data are not complicated and you are not fetching thousands of queries.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on how to code it? Im still a bit confused about where to put the  `Sentiment.filter(neutral=True).count() `. Do I put it in the `views.py` or in the HTML template but where?

Comment: Put it in the views.py and assign it to a variable in your args dictionary that you have in render method, so for example {'neutral': Sentiment.filter(neutral=True).count()}